# Map a list and map into a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
@Getter 
static class Student {
    private Map<Status, Marks> statusAndMarks; 
}

class Status {
}

class Marks {
}

Map<Status, Student> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Student student : studentList) {
    for (Status status : student.getStatusAndMarks().keySet()) {
        map.put(status, student);
    }
}
```

How do I write the above written code in functional style in Java 8?
I have written the following code but how do I write that the result of my code is an immutable map and I do not need to create a map before the lambda?

```
studentList
    .forEach(student -> {
        student
        .getStatusAndMarks()
        .keySet().stream()
        .map(key -> map.put(key, statusKeyImportantMessage));
        });
```

Comment: Your questions looks flawed? what if two students have same Status?

Comment: Two students won't have the same status. The definition of `Status` in my code not very self explanatory - it is more like a rank. Two students can have the same marks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough if you would have used `forEach` for iterating the keyset again as:

```
Map<Status, Student> map = new HashMap<>();
studentList.forEach(student -> 
        student.getStatusAndMarks().keySet()
                .forEach(k -> map.put(k,student)));
```

A similar representation as stated in another answer for this would be

```
Map<Status, Student> map = studentList.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getStatusAndMarks().keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(status -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(status, s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b));
```

Note, the merge function is to overwrite a new student with the same status found later in the iteration. On the other hand, what could be really handy information to query would be a list of students given a status. These can be grouped using a similar stream pipeline as following:

```
Map<Status, List<Student>> statusWiseStudent = studentList.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getStatusAndMarks().keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(status -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(status, s)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```java
studentList.stream()
        .flatMap(student -> student.getStatusAndMarks()
                .keySet().stream().map(status -> Map.entry(status, student)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

`Map.entry` is from Java 9. For lower Java it can be replaced with:

```java
status -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(status, student)
```

Comment: This isn't working. The code can't find `entry` and `toMap()`